# how to use setTimeout and be able to get css class or id?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to color some rectangles, but want it done with one second intervals so I can see them changing color one by one.
[image]

[image]

I have tried using setTimeout(); and have looked at many different answers in stack overflow but I have not been able to get it to work, currently when I use this code the time delay seems to add up and then all the blocks change color at the same time.

```
function dijkstra(){
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++){
    for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        const div = document.getElementById(`${x} ${y}`);
        setTimeout(function() { 
            div.setAttribute('class', 'searched') 
        }, 500); 

    }
}  

}
```

I am using the code below to generate the code

```
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++){
const row = document.createElement('div');
row.setAttribute('class', y);
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    const block = document.createElement('div');

    block.setAttribute('class', 'unsearched');
    block.setAttribute('id', `${x} ${y}`);
    row.appendChild(block);
}
body.appendChild(row);
}
```

and this is what my html looks like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Path Finding</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "navbar">
            <ul id="ulist">
                <li id="start" onclick="dijkstra()"><a>start</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <div class="big_div">
            <div class="big_container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: can you put your html as well

Comment: Why not make a function that sets a color of one element, store the current square in a variable - and call the function for setting the first square, at the end of which you'll have setTimeout, & in the callback of it you'll call the same function for the next square. A recursion basically.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for,  I added a script to generate the grid since you didn't provide it, you can manipulate the animation by adding/removing `x` and `y` from the `timeout` function and also change `100` MS in `y * x * 100`.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    box.classList.add("box");
    box.classList.add(`box_${i}_${j}`);
    container.append(box);
  }
}

function dijkstra() {
  for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      const div = document.querySelector(`.box_${x}_${y}`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        div.classList.add("searched");
      }, y * x * 100);
    }
  }
}

setTimeout(() => {dijkstra();}, 800)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  transition: background-color 1.5s ease;
}
#container {
  width: 220px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.searched {
  background-color: #84dde4;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: it is elegant that you kept OP code and just multiplied the snooze time, I like it :)

Comment: Thank you, its better to keep changes as little as possible ;) Thank you! your answer is good too I would have upvoted yours too but I already reached my upvote limit for today! maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You request 10x10 callback at the same time, this is why all the squares are changed at the same time. Learn more about how `setTimeout()` works, this is a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) about it.

One solution is to use the `setInterval()`, and by the way, it is not really a standard to use space in the `id` field, so I used underscore instead.

```js
const queue = []
for (y = 0; y < 3; y++){
    for(x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        const div = document.getElementById(`${x}_${y}`);
        queue.push(div)
    }
} 

const ticker = setInterval(function() {
  const div = queue.shift()
  div.classList.add('searched') 
  if (queue.length == 0) {
    clearInterval(ticker)
  }
}, 500)
```

```css
.line > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.line > div.searched {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div id="0_0"></div>
  <div id="0_1"></div>
  <div id="0_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div id="1_0"></div>
  <div id="1_1"></div>
  <div id="1_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
<div id="2_0"></div>
<div id="2_1"></div>
<div id="2_2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the JS `EventLoop` all the `setTimeout` functions are running (almost) at the same time (Because of the single-thread property of js they are running one after another, but you won).

So you need to customize `delay` variable for each of the `setTimeout`s
 to make them run with the delay of 500ms after the previous function call.

Below I tried to change a part of code to work:

```js
function dijkstra(){
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            const div = document.getElementById(`${x} ${y}`);
            setTimeout(function() { 
                div.setAttribute('class', 'searched') 
            }, 500 + (y*10 + x)*500);  // change this line

        }
    }
}
```

So `setTimeout`s are being executed in the below sequence:

0.5s
1s
...

---

You can read more about of `Eventloop` from here: [JavaScript Event Loop Explained](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/)

Comment: function calls in the event loop are processed one after another (JS is single-threaded so you can't have many functions running at the same time). Also, the time mentioned in setTimeout is the fastest time in which the function can run.

Comment: @RahulPadalkar thanks for the explanation. I add the `single-thread` to my description. And for the faster time that you mentioned, I have used the word `at least after 500ms` to describe it. Thanks for mentioning anyway.